# Entering Text into a Form and Showing It in a Text Box Below

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

So I have to create an ASP.NET website in C# that includes a user form where several pieces of information are filled out in text boxes.  The idea is to get what the user filled out in the form to appear in a text box below.  As the user types, the text should be appearing in the text box and when that input is changed, the old input should be removed.  I am having trouble getting the user input text to appear in the text box below.  What I tried to do is to have default values appear in the form and the text box below and I was successful in doing that. Hence, I have a starting point but I am stuck as to what to do next.  I included my .aspx page that includes my form and my .cs file that goes along with it that includes the C# code itself.

aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Models.aspx.cs" Inherits="Models" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method ="POST" id="form1" runat="server">
  <p>This page is where the weather forecasting models can be found and this is provided by the tropical tidbits and pivotal weather websites.
The global weather models, along with the mesoscale weather models are included and these can be viewed by the public with no premium membership
needed.</p>
<h3>Registration Form</h3>
    <table>  
               <tr>  
                    <td>Name :</td>  
                    <td>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" NAME="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>  
                    </td>  

               </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Address</td>  
                     <td> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>City</td>  
                    <td>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                    </td>  
                </tr>
                <tr>  
                    <td>State</td>  
                    <td>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                    </td>  
                </tr>
                <tr>  
                    <td>Zip</td>  
                    <td>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                    </td>  
                </tr>
                <tr>  
                    <td>Phone</td>  
                    <td>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                    </td>  
                </tr>
        </table>  
        <p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Height="106px" Width="250px" OnTextChanged="TextBox8_TextChanged" ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

cs page

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class Models : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string input1;
            input1 = TextBox1.Text;
            TextBox2.Text = "Kauffman Road";
            TextBox3.Text = "Annville";
            TextBox4.Text = "Pennsylvania";
            TextBox5.Text = "17003";
            TextBox6.Text = "7173892295";
            TextBox8.Text = "Name: " + TextBox1.Text + "\n" + "Address: " + TextBox2.Text + "\n" + "City: " + TextBox3.Text + "\n" + "State: " + TextBox4.Text + "\n" + "Zip: " + TextBox5.Text + "\n" + "Phone: " + TextBox6.Text;
        }

        protected void TextBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You may save your `TextBox` Text Value in your code.and use `Page.IsPostBack ` for init your `TextBox` text when the page first load.

Comment: Just write some JavaScript there is no point to be making round-trips to the server to simply sync two controls. Search for *javascript text changed event* for examples.

Comment: Or in the `TextBox8_TextChanged` put `puNameOfTextBoxToBeSameAsTextBox8Here.Text = TextBox8.Text` and do the same for the other controls.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
aspx page

```
//Add AutoPostBack="true"
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" NAME="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Do the same thing to other controls.

cs page

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add !IsPostBack
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string input1;
            input1 = TextBox1.Text;
            TextBox2.Text = "Kauffman Road";
            TextBox3.Text = "Annville";
            TextBox4.Text = "Pennsylvania";
            TextBox5.Text = "17003";
            TextBox6.Text = "7173892295";
            TextBox8.Text = "Name: " + TextBox1.Text + "\n" + "Address: " + TextBox2.Text + "\n" + "City: " + TextBox3.Text + "\n" + "State: " + TextBox4.Text + "\n" + "Zip: " + TextBox5.Text + "\n" + "Phone: " + TextBox6.Text;
        }
    }
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox8.Text = "Name: " + TextBox1.Text + "\n" + "Address: " + TextBox2.Text + "\n" + "City: " + TextBox3.Text + "\n" + "State: " + TextBox4.Text + "\n" + "Zip: " + TextBox5.Text + "\n" + "Phone: " + TextBox6.Text;
    }
```

The text of TextBox8 will be changed as text of TextBox1 was changed.